# Is it possible to use values of Set as allowed values in type or interface?

Tags: typescript, types, interface, set

Is it possible to use the values of a set as allowed values for some property in a set like this:

```js
const lateNightCoding = new Set<number>([1,2,3,4])

type someType = {
   someNumbers: ...lateNightCoding
   otherStuff: string
   // more stuff
```

This would help a lot when creating type guards in some cases as I could use the "spread set" as the type in the code and only update the set on one place if needed. This doesn't have to happen during run time.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbkBdW)?  You can't spread an arbitrary type in the type system and I'm not 100% sure what `...lateNightCoding` is intended to be here.  You want `1 | 2 | 3 | 4` or `Array<1 | 2 | 3 | 4>` or something else?

Comment: Recall that Typescript types only exist at compile-time, while a Set's contents are alterable at runtime.

Comment: @jcalz the solution you have behind the link is exactly what I was looking for! I still need to dig in to it a bit to fully understand it. However, now with fresh eyes and mind after sleeping, I realised I had completely over engineered the problem. In my code I have a sort of config file defining a set of rules and properties and I know they wont change during run time, but only if the whole program is updated. However, there's no need to define the properties in question as a Set, but I can easily define them as literal union and use that wherever needed.

Comment: Your solution proposal is very intriguing anyway, so I will look into that and bookmark it. Might become useful at some point :)

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure I understand this answer. I'm wondering if what I want is somewhat similar to this question and how to solve it. Say, I want to have a status property which can only have values of active and inactive. How should I define this property for a class to show that the values are restricted?

Comment: @Naomi Do you need to change the types during runtime? That is not possible. Then if you need to have a set of specific values i.e. strings 'active' / 'inactive' as the types, you can always use the union type `type status = 'active' | 'inactive'`